# Don't Understand JS Recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion

I wrote a simple javascript program to perform recursion.  For some reason it isn't working as I expect it to.  At one level of the recursion I get bcd when I should get cd.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
function recursion_test(i_s) {
    console.log('starting string:' + i_s);
    if (i_s.length <= 1) {
        console.log('base case: ' +i_s);
        return
    } else {
        midPoint = Math.floor(i_s.length /2);
        console.log('mid:' + midPoint, 'l: ' + i_s.substring(0,midPoint), ' r: '+ i_s.substring(midPoint, i_s.length));
        recursion_test(i_s.substring(0, midPoint));
        recursion_test(i_s.substring(midPoint, i_s.length));
    }

}

var start_str = "abcd";
console.log("Done: " + recursion_test(start_str));
```

```
The starting string:abcd
rec_test:32 mid:2 l: ab  r: cd
rec_test:26 starting string:ab
rec_test:32 mid:1 l: a  r: b
rec_test:26 starting string:a
rec_test:28 base case: a
rec_test:26 starting string:b
rec_test:28 base case: b
rec_test:26 starting string:bcd
rec_test:32 mid:1 l: b  r: cd
rec_test:26 starting string:b
rec_test:28 base case: b
rec_test:26 starting string:cd
rec_test:32 mid:1 l: c  r: d
rec_test:26 starting string:c
rec_test:28 base case: c
rec_test:26 starting string:d
rec_test:28 base case: d
rec_test:40 Done: undefinedoutput:
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'm afraid I don't follow the intent of this function. Can you describe how you expect it to work?

Comment: Just a toy program to recursively break down a string and print each character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `let` before `midPoint` otherwise it will make global variable

```js
function recursion_test(i_s) {
    console.log('starting string:' + i_s);
    if (i_s.length <= 1) {
        console.log('base case: ' +i_s);
        return
    } else {
        let midPoint = Math.floor(i_s.length /2);
        console.log('mid:' + midPoint, 'l: ' + i_s.substring(0,midPoint), ' r: '+ i_s.substring(midPoint, i_s.length));
        recursion_test(i_s.substring(0, midPoint));
        recursion_test(i_s.substring(midPoint, i_s.length));
    }

}
var start_str = "abcd";
console.log("Done: " + recursion_test(start_str));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because the variable `midPoint` you defined is a global variable.

```
        recursion_test(i_s.substring(0, midPoint));
        recursion_test(i_s.substring(midPoint, i_s.length));
```

The first `recursion_test` above will change the `midPoint` value to 1, making the second function (where `i_s=='abcd'`) takes `'abcd'.substring(1, 4) -> bcd` as input.

To fix the problem, just add `var` before variable `midPoint`

Answer (score 0):

```js
function Write(str){
     console.log(str);
}

function getData(s,start,end=0){
   if (end == 0) {
       end = s.length;
   }
   return s.substring(start, end)
}

function getMidPoint(s) {
  var midPoint = Math.floor(s.length / 2);
 var left  = getData(s,0, midPoint);
 var right = getData(s,midPoint);
  Write('mid:' + midPoint + ' L: ' + left + ' R: ' + right );
  return midPoint;
}

function recursion_test(i_s) {
  Write(`Starting String: ` + i_s);
  if (i_s.length <= 1) {
    Write('base case: ' + i_s);
  } else {
    let midPoint = getMidPoint(i_s);
    let left = getData(i_s,0,midPoint);
    let right = getData(i_s,midPoint);
    let arr = [left,right];
    arr.forEach(function(e) {
        recursion_test(e);
    });
    return "All Done";
  }

}
var start_str = "abcd";
Write(recursion_test(start_str));
```

This solution simply refactors the code so that it's easier to understand at a glance. Also, note that the variables declared with `let` only exist in block scope.